# Форма передает только последний элемент check_box

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Когда я ставлю/снимаю чекбокс `isCompleted`, происходит submit формы через js и выполняется экшн todos#update, который должен обновить значение в БД. То есть я нажал на чекбокс - значение `todo.isCompleted` должно смениться с `false` на `true`.

По какой-то причине форма передает значение только последнего чекбокса из списка, а не всех. Помогите разобраться

Вот код контроллера:

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController

  def update
    Rails.logger.debug params.require(:todo_check)
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Здесь сама форма, через JS я делаю её submit:

```
<% @project.each do |info| %>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <form class="todos_update", method="post", action="todos/update">
      <%= form_for :todo_check do |f| %>
        <ul> 
          <% info.todos.each do |todo| %>
            <div class="todo_div">
              <%= f.check_box :isCompleted, {class: 'check_todo', checked: todo.isCompleted}, todo.id %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :id, :value => todo.id %>
              <% if todo.isCompleted %><strike><%=todo.text%></strike><%else%><%=todo.text%><%end%>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      <% end %>
    </form>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

JS:

```
$(".check_todo").on('ifChecked', function(){
  $('.todos_update').submit();
});

$(".check_todo").on('ifUnchecked', function(){
  $('.todos_update').submit();
});
```

Comment: Что у вас в логах сервера? Какие параметры прилетают в контроллер?

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно на полученный html через инспектор. `form_for` генерирует тег `form`, поэтому у вас одна форма вложена в другую - это не валидная разметка, которая ведёт к очень странным багам порой